# Get value from one Promise to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am new to JavaScript Promise. Here is the code snippet:

```
 router.post('/hubpost', (req, res) => {
  hubspot.contacts
    .createOrUpdate(req.body.email, {
      properties: [
        {
          property: 'email',
          value: req.body.email,
        },
      ],
    })
    .then((results1) => {
      // Output of results1 is {vid: 121, isNew: true}  
      res.send(results1);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
});

// IN THIS Call, I need to access results. 
router.post('/hubpost_deal', (req, res) => {
  hubspot.deals
    .create({
       associations: {
        associatedVids: [results1.vid],
       },

      properties: [
        {
          name: 'dealname',
          value: `${req.body.firstname} ${req.body.lastname}`,
        },
        {
          name: 'pipeline',
          value: 'xyzzy',
        },
      ],
    })
    .then((results2) => {
      res.send(results2);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
});
```

What I wanted to achieve is, get the response from first call, and use it in second call. In other word, I want to use results from first call and use it in second call.

I have googled and found some solutions to use Database for storing `results` from first call and then retrieving in second call. Or storing on file system. Is that only solution or is there someway I could access the `results` from first call and use in second. Any suggestions and helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this for two separate requests, or a singular request that needs the functionality of both?

Comment: What is `router.post`? Is it an ExpressJS router? Because if so, it doesn't make much sense to rely on the calling endoint (e.g., browser) first calling the one endpoint and then the other.

Comment: It is a single request that needs both functionality.

Comment: Is it? Why is one `/hubpost` and the other `/hubpost_deal` then? How would a single request hit both those endpoints (if indeed, that's what they are)?

Comment: Two routes make no sense. The second route might be accessed without the first being ever called, and they might be accessed by different clients and everything. If you want to make two requests per client, just pass the result of the first as a parameter to the second *on the client*.

Comment: Because `/hubspot` sends `POST` to `contacts` endpoint and `hubpsot_deal` sends `POST` to `deals` endpoints.

Comment: @ParashNathMishra: I don't see how that answers the questions above at all.

Comment: Just use somthing like `Promise.all([hubspot.contacts.createOrUpdate(…),   hubspot.deals.create(…)])` on the single route where you need to both

Comment: @Bergi I tried calling second call for `hubspot_deal` in the result part but I started to get error like `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Comment: @ParashNathMishra I don't know what you did, but (as the error message says) you may not call `res.send()` twice for the same request.

Comment: BTW, I am using https://github.com/brainflake/node-hubspot#deals to create these `POST` calls. I tried making call to `hubspot_api` and in the `.then` of the call, I made another call to `deals` passing the response. The problem was second call was never made. And I got the error as I specified `UnhandedPromiseRejectionWarning`. I need to get response from first call, `contacts` and use it in `deals. Not sure what is correct way :)

Comment: Hubspot isn't the issue. The issue is that you're using two endpoints but want to treat them as a single request. That's fundamentally incorrect.

Comment: The code you've written is all server-side request handling.   To retrieve both results, you have to "hit" each those endpoints individually ... are you trying to do that?  You don't show any code which does.

Comment: What I am trying to do is, when form is submitted, I need to make `POST` request to hubspot `contacts` api and get the response. Use the response and send another `POST` to `deals` endpoint.